# How do I manually install bootstrap in mvc in linux?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I am currently building a web application with Visual Studio Code in Linux. I am trying to apply bootstrap to it manually. I downloaded Bootstrap 4.1.3, unzipped it and place it in the folder wwwroot/lib/bootstrap. I tried adding the 
        
        
    following code to the /View/Shared/_Layout.cshtml file but it did not work.
I have searched around and everyone is talking about Bower being discontinued. I don't know if something like Bower is a requirement but if possible I'd like to set everything up manually in the interest of learning and remaining on the Linux OS. Any help on how to set this up in Linux will be appreciated. 
Update: _Layout.cshtml code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/../../../wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        </environment>

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Concentric</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                          </a>
                          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link Disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </nav>

        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>


        <footer>
            @RenderSection("footer", false)
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show your `Layout.cshtml` file. FYI Bower is a package manager like npm or yarn, which was there by default but most people didn't like it there as a default so it got removed, from my experience it was buggy, good riddance.

Comment: It says it is too long (2080 characters). 
Basically it has the <head> and <body> parts and the navbar code almost exactly as it is in the getbootstrap examples. Edit: Never mind, it has now been added to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use public BootstrapCDN for educational purposes. please check: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Also, I can advice you to check starter templates for orginizing your project better, and acquiring knowledge fast. You do not need to invent wheel again. Some of the starter templates that I can advice are

> https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/master/samples/MusicStore
>   https://github.com/DevExpress/bootstrap-aspnetcore-starter
>   https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal

Comment: I do not have internet at home for the time being. But that's a good one. Also, I'm reading Asp.Net Core 2.0: MVC & Razor Pages for Beginners by Jonas Fagerberg. I just need to get to this part quickly because I want to show something for a small project I am working on. I need to be able to show something and I don't want to show a white page with black text. 

Thank you very much for the links. I will check them out.